# HierarchyRequestError: Errors using toolbar commands for styling of Wysihtml5x editor

Tags: wysihtml5

I'm using the [wysihtml5x](http://voog.github.io/wysihtml/) editor (v0.4.12) and I have found an issue when double-clicking on the toolbar link to change the font colour of the text.

I have prepared a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwudj4m5/11/) with a very minimalistic code that reproduces the problem.

```js
var editor = new wysihtml5.Editor("wysihtml5-editor", {
  toolbar: "wysihtml5-toolbar",
  parserRules: wysihtml5ParserRules,
  contentEditableMode: false
});

var editor2 = new wysihtml5.Editor("wysihtml5-editor2", {
  toolbar: "wysihtml5-toolbar2",
  parserRules: wysihtml5ParserRules,
  contentEditableMode: false
});
```

```css
div[contenteditable="true"] {
  border: solid grey 1px;
  height: 150px;
}
.wysiwyg-color-red {
  color: red;
}
.wysiwyg-color-black {
  color: black;
}
a[data-wysihtml5-command-value="red"] {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a[data-wysihtml5-command-value="black"] {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Voog/wysihtml5/textcolor/parser_rules/advanced_unwrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Voog/wysihtml/0.4.12/dist/wysihtml5x-toolbar.js"></script>
<link href="https://github.com/Voog/wysihtml/blob/0.4.12/examples/css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="wysihtml5-editor" contenteditable="true"><span class="wysiwyg-color-red">Please follow these steps to reproduce the problem:</span>
  <br>1.Click on the editor below just to give focus to it.
  <br>2.Select all the text on the first editor (CTRL+A or using the mouse).
  <br>3.Double click on <span class="wysiwyg-color-red">red</span> link toolbar of the first editor.
  <br>4.Open the console to see the error (F12).
  <br>5.You should be able to see the <span class="wysiwyg-color-red">Uncaught HierarchyRequestError:</span>
  <br>6.Ignore the 'Discontiguous selection is not supported.' error.</div>
<div id="wysihtml5-toolbar" style="display: none;"> <a data-wysihtml5-command="foreColor" data-wysihtml5-command-value="black">black</a>
  <a data-wysihtml5-command="foreColor" data-wysihtml5-command-value="red">red</a> 
</div>
<div id="wysihtml5-editor2" contenteditable="true"><span class="wysiwyg-color-red">The</span> quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
<div id="wysihtml5-toolbar2" style="display: none;"> <a data-wysihtml5-command="foreColor" data-wysihtml5-command-value="black">black</a>
  <a data-wysihtml5-command="foreColor" data-wysihtml5-command-value="red">red</a> 
</div>
```

The error that can be seen on console when following the steps provided on jsFiddle:

`Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Only one element on document allowed.`

I have tested with the latest version of the Wysihtml5x editor and the same problem happens. Please ignore the **Discontiguous selection is not supported.** error as this is an issue that have been addressed already on latest version of the editor.

I am not sure if this error happens only with multiple editors, but I added two as it is what I used when I found the problem.

I have [opened the issue](https://github.com/Voog/wysihtml/issues/177) on the Git Issue Tracker of the project.

It may be related to the [issue opened on Xing base repository](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/issues/469) of this editor.

I could not reproduce the error on Firefox 37.0.2 which makes me think that it does not happen on Firefox.

Your help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been resolved on version [0.5.2](https://github.com/Voog/wysihtml/releases/tag/0.5.2). All of them, including the '*Discontiguous selection is not supported.*'

Thank you very much @oliver-pulges for pointing out the solution replying to the GitHub [issue](https://github.com/Voog/wysihtml/issues/177).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @manetsus I would definitely post it here if I knew what piece of code has resolved the issue. Although I understand your point, and even agree with it in most cases, it is something not possible in this case unfortunately. I'm not sure even if the authors/contributors of the editor know exactly what has fixed the issue. All I wanted with this answer is advise people to update their editor to the newest version if they face a similar error as this will most likely resolve the issue